# How to Install Xfce Desktop Environment from "xfce-4.6.1-src.tar.bz2"?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, xfce

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my other desktop PC which doesn't have internet connection.

I wanted to install XFCE desktop environment on it so I have downloaded the file `xfce-4.6.1-src.tar.bz2`, but I don't know how I can install it.
Please, can somebody guide me step by step?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you want [this file](http://archive.xfce.org/xfce/4.12/fat_tarballs/xfce-4.12.tar.bz2), use another PC to get it.

OK This is going to take you a long time, you must compile each part individually

First put the file in your /home folder and extract the package

```
tar xvjf xfce-4.12.tar.bz2
```

That will extract to a folder called `src`, change to this folder

```
cd src
```

In here are lots of tar.bz2 files, you must compile each one in the following order

```
xfce4-dev-tools (only required if you build from GIT)
libxfce4util
xfconf
libxfce4ui, garcon
exo
xfce4-panel
thunar
xfce4-settings, xfce4-session, xfdesktop, xfwm4, xfce4-appfinder
```

Now this is an issue for you, you need these xfce dependancies,

```
autoconf automake intltool pkgconfig glib2.0 gtk+-2.0 dbus-glib2.0 xfconf gio2.0 libglade2.0 perl libwnck* gudev-1.0
```

If they are not installed the build will just fail, if it fails you can google .debs for all of these and download them on another PC.

Now we will build the first package, extract it

```
tar xvjf xfce4-dev-tools.tar.bz2
```

Enter its directory

```
cd xfce4-dev-tools
```

Now configure

```
./configure
```

Now make

```
make
```

Now install it

```
make install
```

Now go back to the src directory

```
cd ~/src
```

Extract, configure and make the next one

```
tar xvjf libxfce4util.tar.bz2
cd libxfce4util
./configure
make
make install
cd ~/src
```

You get the point, once all packages are successfully made and installed in the correct order, you can log out and select `xfce` from log in screen.

[SOURCE](http://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/install-mind-blowing-xfce-4-12-desktop-environment-linux-features/)